# Verilog garbage input does not result in garbage output

Tags: verilog, fpga, vivado, gtkwave

I am writing a simple Control Unit in verilog. It goes something like this.

```
module controlUnit(
    output reg  wreg,
    input  wire [5:0] op, func
);
    // wreg sub-handles. Beware: wreg is 0 if any of these s high
    wire isBranch = (op[5:3] == 3'b0) & (|op[2:0]); 
    wire isStrWrd = op == 6'b101011;
    wire isJumpReg = (op == 6'd0) & (func == 6'b001000);

    // wreg handle
    always @(*) begin
        if(isBranch | isStrWrd | isJumpReg) 
            wreg <= op == 6'b000011;
        else
            wreg <= 1'b1;
    end
endmodule

module testbench;
    integer i;
    wire out;
    reg [11:0] in;

    controlUnit CU0(
        .wreg(out),
        .op(in[11:6]), .func(in[5:0])
    );

    initial begin
        $dumpfile("test.vcd");
        $dumpvars(0, testbench);

        #4 in = 0;
        for(i=0; i<1024; i=i+1) begin
            #1 in = i;
        end
        #1 in = 10'hXX;    // Garbage input here
        #1000;
    end
endmodule
```

However in simulation, the wreg signal is a solid logical HIGH when the input becomes garbage. I have seen this behaviour with iverilog-10/GTKwave and Vivado 2019.1. Following is the waveform:
[image: Garbage as input, but logic HIGH as output.]

So, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only set 10 of your 12 input bits to `x`; the 2 MSBs are 0.  You should set all of your input signals to `x`.  This is probably unrelated to your problem, but I think it is what you intended.  Change:

```
    #1 in = 10'hXX;    // Garbage input here
```

to:

```
    #1 in = {12{1'bx}};    // Garbage input here
```

When the signals in `if(isBranch | isStrWrd | isJumpReg)` are `x`, the `if` is false, and the `else` is executed, which sets `wreg` to 1 (`wreg <= 1'b1`), not `x`.  This answers the question of why the Verilog simulator assigns `wreg` to 1 when all the inputs are `x`.  This is the way the simulator is designed to work.

---

Using the ternary operator equivalent code will set `wreg` to `x` when the inputs are `x`:

```
always @(*) begin
    wreg = (isBranch | isStrWrd | isJumpReg) ? (op == 6'b000011) : 1'b1;
end
```

Note that using a blocking assignment (`=`) is recommended for combinational logic.